# Getting A Random EOF Error

Tags: python, sockets, syntax-error, eof

So i am trying to make a little chat server with python sockets but im getting this error

```
File "chatserver.py", line 40
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I have checked all parenthesis and the like and have no clue what is wrong here is the code

```
from socket import *
import logging
import Colorer

CONNECTED = []

HOST = ''
PORT = 9555
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(2)

def send_message(sock, message):
    for socket in CONNECTED:
        if socket != s and socket != sock:
            try:
                socket.send(message)
            except:
                socket.close()
                CONNECTED.remove(socket)

print ("Server Started")

   while 1: 

    connection, addr = s.accept()

    if connection:
        CONNECTED.append(connection)
        print ("Connection from" % addr)

    else:
        for sock in CONNECTED:
            try:
                message = sock.recv(1024)

                if message:
                    send_message(sock, str(sock.getpeername() + '<< ' + message))
                    print (str(sock.getpeername()) + ' ' + message)
```

If anyone could help me with this problem that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `try:` should be followed by `except:` and / or `finally:` EOF in py3.x can mean unexpected indent check all your indents as well as parenthesis. good luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple syntax errors. Most obvious is the messed-up indentation (which may have been different in your actual code), but you also have a `try` block without any `except` or `finally`. Why do you have that? Did you forget to write a `finally` block?

Answer (score 1):

python 2.7 gives a more usable error:

```
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

whereas python 3.3 says just

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Thus it is the missing `except/finally/else` after the try.